# proxy in package.json for localhost

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I create graphql server in adress  `http://localhost:4000/graphql` and I have server in `http://localhost:3000`

in package.json i put

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

but my result in this image https://prnt.sc/10vs0nk

I use create-react-app.

proxy doesnt work ? How to fix this ?

Comment: Can you share your package.json contents? Maybe it's in the wrong place?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?  I have the exact same issue