# I added a proxy to my package.json but app is not using that proxy

Tags: reactjs, flask

Very similar to this question that was never answered:  [proxy in package.json for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66812122/proxy-in-package-json-for-localhost)

I have a flask backend running on localhost:5000 and an ionic/react frontend running on localhost:8100

I added a `"proxy":"http://localhost:5000",` to my `package.json` file.

When I run a particular function:

```
const logitin = async ({ username, password }) => {
            try {
            await fetch(`/userlookup`, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(username, password),
            });
            return console.log('logitin', username, password);
            } catch (error) {
            console.log("error time!", username, password);
            return false;
            }
            };
        logitin({username, password})
```

I get a 500 status code error in the console that says `POST http://localhost:8100/userlookup`

I expected it to look at `http://localhost:5000/userlookup` because that's what I thought I was doing the proxy for and also that's where the actual route is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put curly braces around `username, password` in the body line.